# Drag and Drop boxes value send to e-mail

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, email, drag-and-drop

i am currently working on an drag and drop system.

I would like to add an form that sends the outcome of the dragged boxes(location there currently in set by visitor) to my e-mail. Code is below.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    /* show the move cursor as the user moves the mouse over the panel header.*/
    #draggablePanelList .panel-heading {
        cursor: move;
    }
</style>

<!-- Bootstrap 3 panel list. -->
<ul id="draggablePanelList" class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel too.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
    </li>
</ul>

    jQuery(function($) {
    var panelList = $('#draggablePanelList');

    panelList.sortable({
        // Only make the .panel-heading child elements support dragging.
        // Omit this to make then entire <li>...</li> draggable.
        handle: '.panel-heading', 
        update: function() {
            $('.panel', panelList).each(function(index, elem) {
                 var $listItem = $(elem),
                     newIndex = $listItem.index();

                 // Persist the new indices.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

All help is welcome!

Comment: Maby like an feature that makes a screenshot of it and then put's that as attachment into the form. Just an thought :)